# Adding values in iOS using float

Tags: iphone, ios, math, floating-point

I'm looking to sum two values i have and then display these as a new UILabel.

I've read online about using float however i'm coming unstuck, here's my code below..

The sum i'm looking to do is : shippingLabel (Shipping Costs) + costLabel (Product Price) then having this then accessible in a new UILabel to display (TotalPrice)

The issue i'm having is that the value's are returning as 00.00

```
//TotalPrice
// Grab the values from the UITextFields.
float ShippingValue = [[shippingLabel text] floatValue];
float CostValue = [[costLabel text] floatValue];

// Sum them.
float floatNum = ShippingValue + CostValue;
TotalPrice.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];

TotalPrice = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f, 25.0f)];
TotalPrice.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"5b5b5b"];
TotalPrice.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
TotalPrice.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
TotalPrice.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[self.view addSubview:TotalPrice];
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.  What happens that you consider incorrect?  What should happen instead?

Comment: Why is your data stored in labels? Labels should only be used to display other data. You should keep the actual data in appropriate instance variables and not have to convert the label's text to get your original numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to accurately answer this considering you haven't stated what the problem is exactly. But, the most obvious things that jump out at me are:

1: You are assigning a text value to `TotalPrice` before you create it. The lines should appear in the following order.

```
TotalPrice = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f, 25.0f)];
TotalPrice.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];
```

2: Your comment indicates that you want to multiply the two values together, but you use an addition operator. This probably isn't your problem, but we all make silly mistakes.

```
// Multiply them.
float floatNum = ShippingValue * CostValue;
```

3: The float value of shippingLabel's text maybe inaccurate due to non numerical values in the label's text.

**Side note:**  You should name your variables like this `totalPrice` instead of `TotalPrice`. It is common practice to use lower case first characters on instances and capitals on classes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, you are expecting there will be a UILabel with a total number on it,but truth is you see no total number at all. I think here is the problem

```
TotalPrice.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];
```

You are trying to make TotalPrice's text the total number while TotalPrice haven't been allocated, so TotalPrice won't get a thing. You may just put this line after TotalPrice is allocated,it should work. May it help.